# Obtener resultado de consulta en php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy desarrollando en php con mysql mi pregunta es como puedo obtener el resultado de una consuta que ejecuto con un  procedimiento almacenado y enviarlos a un VO a los setter de 
`$usuario`

```
 public function ingresarUsuario($correo, $contraseña)
    {

        $Conexion = new CConexion();
        $conn = $Conexion->getConexion();

        $usuario = new CUsuario();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL Us_IngresarLogin (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $correo, $contraseña);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener respuesta de un procedimiento es lo mismo que de una consulta

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL Us_IngresarLogin (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $correo, $contraseña);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();
if(!ISSET($result["email"])){
    /*FALLO LOGIN, CODIGO PARA REDIRIGIR*/
}
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = $result;
/*SESION ALMACENADA, CODIGO COMPLEMENTARIO*/
```